# Php debug all params in method

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have this function in **PHP**:

```
public function FunctionName(string $var1, array $var2)
{
   var_dump($var1, $var2);
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to dump all method parameters without specifying all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will dump all defined variables in function.

```
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Comment: This will include any variables manually defined in the function. If you want that, that's fine, but if you really only want the function arguments, `func_get_args()` might be a better fit.